# Change type of column in a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint

How can I change the type of my column in a sharepoint list in the JSON code?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, per my knowledge, column formatting could only change the display in the column field instead of column type.

For more details of column formatting, you could refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint JSON formatting can only be used to customize the display of columns and views in SharePoint lists and libraries.

You can only change the display of column to another type.

For example: [Turn field values into hyperlinks (basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#turn-field-values-into-hyperlinks-basic) - This example shows how to turn a text field into a hyperlink

OR

You can set the value of column using `setValue`.

For example:

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "[$FieldName]",
  "customRowAction":{
    "action": "setValue",
    "actionInput": {
      "FieldInternalName_1": "FieldValue_1",
      "FieldInternalName_2": "FieldValue_2",
    }
  }
}
```

---

But, you cannot change the actual column/data type in column settings.

**Documentation**:

1. [column formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [view formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)